PWA App Cache Not Updating Properly After Publishing Updates
I have built a Progressive Web App (PWA) using Vite and vite-plugin-pwa and published it on Google Play. The PWA works fine, but I encounter an issue when I publish updates to the backend site linked to the PWA.
The problem is that the app doesn't immediately reflect the updates. Here's what happens:

After publishing the updates, I open the app, but I don't see the changes.
If I close the app and open it again (sometimes multiple times), the update finally takes effect.
If I open the site in an incognito browser window, the updates are applied immediately.

Here is my vite.config.js configuration for the PWA:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { VitePWA } from "vite-plugin-pwa";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    VitePWA({
      registerType: "autoUpdate",
      injectRegister: "auto",
      start_url: "/",
      display: "standalone",
      srcDir: "src",
      manifest: {
        name: "NAME",
        short_name: "NAME",
        description: "DESCRIPTION",
        theme_color: "#ffffff",
        icons: [
          {
            src: "/web-app-manifest-192x192.png",
            sizes: "192x192",
            type: "image/png",
          },
          {
            src: "/web-app-manifest-512x512.png",
            sizes: "512x512",
            type: "image/png",
          },
        ],
      },
      devOptions: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      workbox: {
        maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
        runtimeCaching: [
          {
            urlPattern: ({ request }) => request.mode === "navigate",
            handler: "NetworkFirst",
          },
          {
            urlPattern: /^\/index.html$/,
            handler: "CacheFirst",
            options: {
              cacheName: "index-cache",
              expiration: {
                maxEntries: 2,
                maxAgeSeconds: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, // Cache for 1 day
              },
            },
          },
          {
            urlPattern: /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|webp)$/,
            handler: "CacheFirst",
            options: {
              cacheName: "image-cache",
              expiration: {
                maxEntries: 500,
                maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // Cache for 30 days
              },
            },
          },
          {
            urlPattern:
              /^https:\/\/quran\.ksu\.edu\.sa\/ayat\/safahat1\/.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|webp)$/,
            handler: "CacheFirst",
            options: {
              cacheName: "external-images",
              expiration: {
                maxEntries: 100,
                maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // Cache for 30 days
              },
              cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [0, 200], // Cache only valid responses
              },
            },
          },
          {
            urlPattern:
              /^https:\/\/static\.abstractapi\.com\/country-flags\/.*\.png$/,
            handler: "CacheFirst",
            options: {
              cacheName: "external-images2",
              expiration: {
                maxEntries: 100,
                maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // Cache for 30 days
              },
              cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [0, 200], // Cache only valid responses
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        skipWaiting: false,
        clientsClaim: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
});

I had set:
Register Type: autoUpdate
My Questions:
Why does the app require multiple reopenings to reflect updates? Is it related to the skipWaiting or clientsClaim or RegisterType settings?
Is there a way to make the updates take effect immediately upon publishing?
Should I implement a custom update notification to prompt users to reload the app when updates are available? If so, how can I achieve this?
Any guidance or suggestions to improve this behavior would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Can one help me ?
